# Google text search API returns results located in USA

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, text-search

I'm using Google's text search with location bias by including geoPoints in URL but for some reason, 3 results out of 60 are of USA while the geoPoints I provide are in India.
I want all the results to be location biased.

URL that I'm constructing:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Manufacturing companies near me&location=28.7364321184373,77.13676393032074&key=${GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query suggests a location, "near me", which may override the location parameter.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text#location

[image]

Comment: thanks. but out of 60 results, only 3 are USA locations, rest all 57 are location baised. do you know why that might be?

Comment: would be of great help if you can let me know what do you think about this